# Display Product attribute in cart page

Tags: magento-1.9

I try to display Product attribute in cart page like this

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem()?>
<?php $_product= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId()) ?>
<?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('disable')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
```

all product display same value only what mistake i done here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change code

```
$_product= Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId())
```

to:

```
$_product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId())
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')` with `Mage::getModel('catalog/product')`